# Yii init singleton ApplicationComponent onBeginRequest

Tags: php, yii

I am developing an component that will take a GET variable from the URL, store it in an accessible variable and place it in a cookie. If the GET variable is not set it will load the cookie value into the accessible variable:

```
MyComponent extends ApplicationComponent {

  protected $_var = null;

  public init(){
    // if isset($_GET['var']), set value to $_var and cookie;
    // elseif cookie set value to $_var;
    // else nothing; 
  }

  public getVar(){
    return $_var;
  }
}
```

I always want one instance of the component and I want to run init on every frontend request (even if it is not explicitly referred to).

How do I hook this up? I am aware of the onBeginRequest, but doesn't this only allow static methods? 
I could hack it in and set an app component in a separate method, but that doesn't sit well.. I'd like this to be portable across sites and set-up in my config if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add it to the `preload` section of your config:

<kbd>protected/config/main.php</kbd>

```
return array(
    // some parameters
    'preload' => array( 'myComponent' ),

    'components' => array(
        'myComponent' => array(
            'class' => 'path.to.your.component.MyComponent'
        ),
    ),
);
```

This will automatically instantiate the component on each frontend request. Please refer to the [corresponding section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.use#application-component) of The Definitive Guide to Yii.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, I thought there would be a standard way. I confess, I do find the Yii documentation tricky to navigate at times.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, I agree. They have very well documented class reference though.